# Update table column based on value of key in other column POSTGRES

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My table name is companies having is_nse,a boolean column and exchanges column type json having value like "[{"exchange":"NSE","ticker":"ABC"},{"exchange":"BSE","ticker":"ABC"}]"

Now i have this query

```
 update companies set is_nse=0 from (SELECT is_nse, obj.value->>'exchange' As exch FROM  (SELECT * FROM   companies WHERE  sector is not null) u JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(exchanges) obj(value) ON obj.value->>'exchange' = 'BSE')y
```

But it is updating all the rows in companies table rather than rows of the subquery.Can anybody tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the `companies` in the `update` to the `from` clause.  Assuming you have an id, you can do:

```
update companies
    set is_nse = 0
    from (select c.*
          from companies u join lateral
               json_array_elements(exchanges) obj(value)
               on obj.value->>'exchange' = 'BSE'
          where u.sector is not null
         ) y
    where y.companyid = companies.companyid ;
```